# The bean 'methodSecurityInterceptor', defined in class path resource and overriding bean is disabled

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE and using some third party framework to perform security specific activities. This third party library using spring security 4.2.3.RELEASE.

When I ran the application, I got below error.

```
The bean 'methodSecurityInterceptor', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/thirdparty/configSecurityConfig.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

I know, I can solve the problem by setting below configuration.

```
spring:
   main:
      allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

But is there any way to specify my application to use the spring security (4.2.3.RELEASE) of third party library not from spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE.